# How to read the JSON response by php

Tags: php

I got the JSON response from Facebook. How to retrieve the value of `$id` & `$post_id`?

```
    $response = json_decode ( file_get_contents($graph_url) );
    $id = $response.id;
    $post_id = $response.post_id;    

        print_r( $response );   
        print_r( $id );
        print_r( $post_id );
```

Outputs:

```
stdClass Object ( [id] => 232160686920835 [post_id] => 231794566957447_232160693587501 )
```

No output of `$id` & `$post_id`
...
...

Comment: You are mistaking PHP for javascript ;). Just use `$id = $response->id`

Answer (score 4):

Your object syntax is wrong. Use:

```
$id = $response->id;
$post_id = $response->post_id;    

print_r( $response );   
print_r( $id );
print_r( $post_id );
```

Or if you prefer to work with arrays, you can put `true` as the second argument for json_decode:

```
$response = json_decode ( file_get_contents($graph_url), true );
$id = $response['id'];
$post_id = $response['post_id'];    

print_r( $response );   
print_r( $id );
print_r( $post_id );
```

Answer (score 0):

In PHP OOP

`->` is used instead of `.` like in Java or other languages.